# What is the relative and absolute deadline?

Tags: operating-system

I'm reading an paper about EDF scheduling algorithm and I'm going to implement it after get it. I couldn't find any acceptable answer for it so I asked this question.
does anybody know this question's answer?

Comment: It's hard to tell what your actual question is. Moreover, this appears to be off-topic for SO. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 3):

There is no mystery in these terms

- *relative deadline* is a deadline relative to *start* of the job (start of the thread, ...),
- *absolute deadline* is a specific point in time.

So a periodic job - for example a task that is executed every second - can have constant *relative deadline* - for example *100ms* - but on each run its *absolute deadline* will be different (11:10:00.100, 11:10:01.100, 11:10:02.100, ...).

See page 335 - http://books.google.pl/books?id=iilIj3JXNrAC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pl&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false (really good source of info about operating systems)